# muscadine wine fermenting

Tags: bottling, wine, fermentation

I made wine last fall (2015) September and racked it one time.  After that
I left it in the carboys.  It stopped fermenting and cleared.  I never bottled it, it's still in there with the airator top on it.  Is it safe to bottle.  It looks good and doesn't smell. I followed the directions to ferment it and racking it.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate in http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If the aerator top is still working, meaning that no air has gotten to the wine, you should still be able to bottle it. The best way to know is to taste it. If it tastes right, you should be fine.